# How can a child class can change the value of parent class instance variable

Tags: java

How can a child class can change the value of parent class instance variable.I have tried it using super.variable name in child class but when i print parent.variable name i can see changes are not reflected in parent variable

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I think you should use a Java book instead of stackoverflow...

Comment: Child already inherits (public and protected)variables from its parent, thus you can access and change it by using  this.variable.

Comment: public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   
  Parent p=new Parent();
    
    Child c= new  Child();
    c.changeValue();
    
    //not sure why output of this line showing 12 i expected it to be 5
     System.out.println(p.j);
  }
}

 class Parent
{
 public int j=12;
  
}
 class Child extends Parent
{
 public void changeValue()
 {
   super.j=5;
   System.out.println(this.j);
   System.out.println(super.j);
  
}
}

Comment: @Raptor i can change the value of child that is not an issue but i would like to enquire if parent actual value can be changed as i had tried to change in sample code

Comment: Please **edit** your question with additional information like code, etc. Do not use comments for that.

Answer (score 2):

Updating parent's variable with `parent.variable` is a wrong thought on OOP. When you extend the parent class, think like your child class became one with the parent, they are not separated anymore, so think like the variable is child's from now on. But just the slice difference is `public` `private` definitions which set the visibility of each item of classes. So, in the sample below, I just defined a private variable for the parent so the child won't be able to see it but the child is able to update the variable via the public getter setters. This is because we are using getters and setters, to provide the encapsulation because it is only relevant to the Parent class. Please investigate the code to understand more:

```
class Main {

    public static class Parent {
        private int variable;

        public int getVariable() {
            return variable;
        }

        public void setVariable(int variable) {
            this.variable = variable;
        }
    }

    public static class Child extends Parent {

        private int childVadiable;

        public Child() {

        }

        public int getChildVadiable() {
            return childVadiable;
        }

        public void setChildVadiable(int childVadiable) {
            this.childVadiable = childVadiable;
        }

        public void updateParentVariable(int value) {
            this.setVariable(value);
        }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Child child = new Child();
        child.updateParentVariable(5);
        System.out.println(child.getVariable());
        //Result it '5'
    }

}
```